# How to bind textarea id to tiptap editor?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tiptap

I'm kinda new to Tiptap. I want to use textarea element from another component(FormComponent) instead of using the content property(editor option). Is this even possible?

```js
const TiptapEditor = () => {
  const editor = useEditor({
    element: document.getElementById('description'), // It didn't work.
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: 'Hello World! ️', // I don't want this
  })

  return <EditorContent editor={editor} />
}

export default TiptapEditor
```

Another component where the textarea element is.

```js
const FormComponent = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting, isSubmitted, isDirty, isValid },
  } = useForm<ExampleType>({
    mode: 'onChange',
    resolver: zodResolver(ExampleSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      description: '',
    },
  })
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)} noValidate>
      <TiptapEditor /> // obviously, this does not work at the moment.
      <textarea
          id="description" // I want to use this textarea so that I don't have to add another styling.
          placeholder={DESCRIPTION_PLACEHOLDER}
          {...register('description')}
        />
      <button></button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

I can't really find examples or documentation related to this issue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand on why you do not want to use the content field?

I use Tiptap in forms, with react hook forms. Rather than using register I use controller:

```js
const CompactNotepadController: React.FC<CompactNotepadControllerProps> = ({
  name,
  required = false,
  readOnly = false,
  active = !readOnly,
  value,
  label,
  contacts,
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      rules={{ required }}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value: rhfValue, ref } }) => {
        return (
          <Input.Wrapper ref={ref} label={label} required={required}>
            <Box
              sx={{
                border: active ? "1px solid #ced4da" : "1px solid transparent",
                borderRadius: "4px",
                "&:focus-within": {
                  borderColor: "#fd7e14",
                },
              }}
            >
              <Notepad
                initialValue={rhfValue}
                onChange={onChange}
                readOnly={readOnly}
                contacts={contacts}
              />
            </Box>
          </Input.Wrapper>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

The content field is just used as initial value, and the editor will handle the state and I just feed back the changes to the form.

If you could share more info about why the content field is your problem, I could try to expand on my answer.

##### Edit

This is how the notepad component could look like

```js
interface NotepadProps {
  readOnly?: boolean;
  initialValue?: string;
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
}

export const Notepad: React.FC<NotepadProps> = ({
  readOnly = false,
  initialValue = "",
  onChange,
}) => {
  const preProcessedValue = useMemo(() => {
    return preProcesseInitialContent(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  const editor = useEditor({
    onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
      onChange?.(postProcessContent(editor.getHTML()));
    },
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: preProcessedValue,
  });

  // Force set content on edit/read only change
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!editor) {
      return undefined;
    }

    if (editor.isEditable !== !readOnly) {
      editor.commands.setContent(preProcessedValue);
      editor.setEditable(!readOnly);
    }
  }, [editor, preProcessedValue, readOnly]);

  return (
    <>
      {editor && !readOnly && <NotepadCornerMenu editor={editor} />}
      <EditorContent editor={editor} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Disco. Maybe I should try with the controller not the register. I'd like to know how the Notepad component looks like.

Comment: Updated the answer with a example of how the notepad component could look like. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: @Disco what's `preProcesseInitialContent` function? How it works? I am trying implement resetting the content after submit. However, it is not resetting and I also wrapped it inside `Controller`

Comment: `preProcesseInitialContent`is just a function that I run to change some of the html to make sure it can be picked up by my custom extensions. Its more of a hack that I used since I could not get tables to work the way I wanted.
If you want to reset the content in the editor, you will have to force it with setContent as I do when I switch between readonly/editable. 
You can also just change the `key` of the component in the parent to force a rerender that should reinit the editor and set it to the initial value.